# Using print if a window is clicked?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to create a program in Python turtle graphics so that if the window is clicked it will print "hello." Is there any certain code to be used here?

Comment: there are many tutorials on internet and many answers on SO but maybe start with [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html) to find function which catchs mouse click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, here's a minimal turtle program that I believe does what you ask:

```
from turtle import *

onscreenclick(lambda x, y: write("Hello!", font=('Arial', 18, 'normal')))

done()
```

Make sure to click on the turtle window's title bar to make it active and then click anywhere on the window to get it to print "Hello!".  You'll want to read more about the above functions, as @furas suggests.

Comment: The question is off-topic, so please flag instead.

Comment: @Coal_, I read the SO page describing [what is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and my take away is that the OP's question is more on-topic than off.  (There's nothing about it that would attract opinionated answers and spam.)  Please cite from that page where the OP went wrong.  I also believe that downvoting my answer based not on the quality of its content but on one's opinion of the OP's question is a worse infraction than I may, or may not, have made.

Comment: SO seems to have become very hostile to beginners. While this doesn't affect me, everyone was once a beginner.

Comment: @xaav OP asked us to write code for them without showing any previous research on the topic. It's not an act of hostility to close to vote (or downvote), it's quality assurance for the website. If we keep answering these types of questions, they're gonna keep coming back. In hindsight, I shouldn't have downvoted this answer, but my vote is locked now.